# How to sync some folders in two different Github repos?

Tags: python, bash, github, git-bash

I'm trying to sync some folders within some trees in one repo to another repo with the same trees. I can't really edit the structure of the repos because the repos control the Periscope Data spaces I have.

So within a tree, there're folders that contain data and I want to sync some of the folders within the tree between both repos.

I've been reading but still not sure how to proceed. I read this article about copying single files from one repo to another but not sure how to apply this to copying multiple folders.

https://junhopark.com/posts/2016/07/14/copying-a-single-file-from-one-git-repo-to-another-git-repo-while-maintaining-commit-history

At the end of the day, I was some of the folders within the trees to be identical between repos but not all of the folders.

Update: looking to- create a Python script that will overwrite the files in the 2nd repo once I change them in the first.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for submodules. Have you read about those?

Comment: I read some but I guess what I really want to do is create a Python script that will overwrite the files in the 2nd repo once I change them in the first.